# Obstruction of smooth structure

Tags: co.combinatorics, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, 4-manifolds

The first 24 lectures of Jacob Lurie on Geometric Topology [1]
gave a concise introduction to the comparison of smooth manifolds
and piecewise-linear manifold. In the first five lectures, it is
shown that any smooth manifold has an essentially unique
triangulation, and therefore any smooth manifold is naturally a
piecewise linear manifold (**smooth -> PL**). The construction of
the triangulation is quite explicit.

**In this question, I aim to understand the construction in the
opposite direction (i.e. PL -> smooth).** Of course, the
construction does not always make sense, which is a theme of the
lecture: piecewise-linear manifolds are in general inequivalent
to smooth manifolds, by the following facts:

- In dimension $\leq 6$, two kinds of structures are equivalent (cf
  the end of lecture 23).
- In dimension 7, any piecewise-linear manifold can be smoothed
  (cf the end of lecture 23), but not necessarily uniquely (e.g.
  Milnor's 7-sphere).
- In general, there are piecewise-linear manifold that cannot be
  smoothed.

Unfortunately, the proof of these are quite abstract.
Essentially, the topologists had reduced the classification of
smooth structures on a fixed piecewise-linear manifold to a
problem in homotopy theory (cf lecture 17). It is a wonderful
theory, but it also makes the picture harder to see concretely.
In spirit, everything here is just obstruction theory, which has
a pictorial/geometrical/concrete description, so I believe my
question below makes sense:

**Questions**:

1. Fix a piecewise-linear manifold M that admits at least one
   smoothing, and fix a triangulation of M. How do we explicitly
   construct a smoothing from the triangulation?
2. In dimension $\leq6$, it is known that every piecewise-linear
   manifold admits a(n essentially) unique smoothing. Can we
   explicitly construct a path linking any two smoothings
   constructed using the method in an answer to the previous
   question?
3. What is the smallest (e.g. in dimension; or simplest) example
   of a piecewise-linear manifold that admits no smoothing? And
   how does the construction in 1 fail in this case?

#### Reference

- [1] [https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/937.html](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/937.html)

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of "explicit" in the first two questions. As for the last, what do you mean by "smallest"? Do you mean that it has the least number of simplices in a triangulation? I do not believe anybody have done such calculations, this sounds quite hard to me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan By "explicit" I mean to see how to construct a smooth structure and a path, but rather than just seeing their existence.

Comment: No, this does not explain anything. Suppose somebody asks you to construct explicitly a diffeomirphis between two curves, but does not tell you in what form these curves are given, only that they are smooth compact and connected. What such a request could possibly mean?

Comment: "Fix a piecewise-linear manifold M that admits at least one smoothing, and fix a triangulation of M. How do we explicitly construct a smoothing from the triangulation?" seems to me just as hard as "Fix a set that admits at least one element. How do we explicitly construct an element?"

Comment: You get your point. What I had in mind was not explicitly spelled in the original post indeed, but I did indicate that someone can use "the picture of obstruction theory" to give such a construction from a triangulation. Namely, one can start by constructing a smooth structure for a neighborhood of the 0-skeleton, and try to extend that to the 1-skeleton, and so on. I was hoping to see such construction, and how one would encounter obstacle in this fashion.

Comment: Maybe you would like reading Hatcher's note "The torus trick for surfaces", which explains the existence and uniqueness of smooth structures on surfaces by a sort of obstruction theory argument, where one computes that the obstructions are zero by hand.

Comment: I am puzzled that co.combinatorics is the only high-level tag on this question. Surely this is more a topological question than a combinatorial question, and should have one of the three top-level topology tags?